# How to remove device from apple developer account while resetting device list

Tags: ios, iphone, device, membership, iphone-developer-program

We have already reached to iPhone device limit so we are not able to add new iPhone to our developer accounts device list.
We have renewed our membership for our apple's developer account.
and it is asking us to reset our device list.
but when we proceed to reset device list, but we are not able to remove device from device list.
[image: In first image it asks to select devices which you want to carry over to this membership year.]

but on next page it is not changing the count of no of devices able to register
[image]

[image]

So it is confusing for me will it remove the deselected devices and let me add new devices instead of them or the it will just disable them.

Answer (score 4):

I'm about to go through same process.
The page is somewhat confusing unless you read all the info carefully.
Those devices you **check** will be **carried over** and will keep counting towards total device count.
Those devices you **uncheck** will be **removed**.

However, when I uncheck all the devices, I get this:
[image]

This is super confusing.
If I'm removing all the devices, I'm expecting the count to go all the way up to 100 again.
Unless it tells me the count **before** reset, in which case this information only confuses the user, I want to see what device counts I get **after** I reset.

**Update**

So I went ahead and reset the list.
Once you do that, you get this page:
[image]

So apart from a bit confusing message before hitting reset, it works OK.

Just need to remember that to remove a device you need to **uncheck** it.

Comment: I agree that this is ridiculously confusing. Based on what the initial page says, it appears that I'm losing out on device count just for removing the devices. Thank you for posting your update, @i4niac. This visually confirmed that this was the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your acknowledgement says that, once you reset devices after that you can not reset device in until one year or you renew your developer account again. You can disable any device but it is count in your maximum device limit you can say `100`. That's it!

You should refer [Apple - Resetting your Device List](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/),

> If you are the Team Agent for your Apple Developer Program team, you can reset your list of development devices each year using Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles. You can register up to 100 of each device type for testing and Ad Hoc distribution per membership year. At the start of your new membership year, you and any Admins on your team will be presented with the option to remove listed devices and restore the available device count to 100 when you first sign in to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.
>
> Although you may remove a device from your account during the year, it will continue to count against your device limit. When resetting your list, make sure to remove all devices you no longer use for development before adding any new devices.

Comment: so my question is after reseting device list will i be able to add new device to list

Comment: Of course! But don't forget to remove unnecessary devices! Inshort you can have maximum 100 devices including disable ones! You can reset once yearly!

Comment: Yes I know that i can have only 100 devices but my question is I have already added 100 devices to my developer account I want to remove some devices from my developer account so will resetting list remove unselected devices and will let me add new devices instead of them?

Comment: Resetting will remove selected devices !

Comment: Reset will remove selected devices and since you already added 100 devices, so until your current years end, you won't be able to add new devices.

Answer (score -1):

Unchecked devices will stay with your developer account. Checked devices will be removed from your account. So check the devices you want to disable or no longer needed. Then check acknowledge button and click to Reset button to reset the device list. Let me know if that makes sense.

Please remember as said in the acknowledgement box that, during this membership year these disabled devices will be counted as total number of devices you can add in your profile.

Comment: The page clearly says "Select the devices you wish to carry over to this membership year or deselect the devices you want to remove.", so the logic is inverse. Unchecked devices will **not** stay with the developer account.

Answer (score -2):

You can still add device even the list is full.
Just connect your device and run your app on Xcode. A prompt will pop-up and click "Register device".

Comment: And you will get an error `(5405) Your development team has reached the maximum number of registered iPhone devices.`